# Is there any way to have a base-class method called after the child's init?

Tags: python

I have a class hierarchy - which may be multiple inheritance, for example:

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self):
    print("Base")

class A(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print("A")

class B(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print("B")

class C(A, B):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print("C")

x = C()
```

will print

```
Base
B
A
C
```

as expected.

what I'd like to do is somehow print `Done` after this is all finished, by defining a method or similar in `Base` that will be called when `C.__init__()` has completed.

What I can't do:

1. Put code in `Base.__init__` as that gets called too early.
2. Put code in `C.__init__` as I want this to apply to all potential subclasses

I've tried various things with metaclasses and haven't managed to make anything work yet - any clever ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `__init__` is handled by the call to `type.__call__`, once `__new__` has returned. You could define a metaclass that overrides `__call__` to handle your post-init code; I believe this is the only way to avoid having the code be called prematurely whenever you subclass, since `__call__` won't be invoked for or by any of the ancestor classes.

```
class PostInitHook(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        rv = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Done")
        return rv

class Base(metaclass=PostInitHook):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Base")

...
```

More generally, you could replace `print("Done")` a class specific hook, for example,

```
class PostInitHook(type):
    def __new__(metacls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(metacls, *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            cls._post_init
        except AttributeError:
            raise TypeError("Failed to define _post_init")
        return cls

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        rv = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        rv._post_init()
        return rv

class Base(metaclass=PostInitHook):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Base")

    def _post_init(self):
        print("Done")
```

Then

```
>>> a = A()
Base
A
Done
>>> b = B()
Base
B
Done
>>> c = C()
Base
B
A
C
Done
>>> class D(C):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super().__init__()
...     print("D")
...
>>> d = D()
Base
B
A
C
D
Done
>>>
```

Comment: Being hesitant to use metaclasses without good reason, I checked how the `dataclasses` module implements its `__post_init__` function. No metaclasses, but the implementation is a good deal more complicated, as it essentially constructs a `class` statement dynamically and uses `exec` to execute the statement. That's not something I would want to try to demonstrate correctly here, but you can see [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/dataclasses.py) if you are interested.

Comment: (Note, though, that the dataclass `__post_init__` is called *by* the generated `__init__`, not after, which means you would have to adapt your generated `class` statement appropriately.)